# El display none no desaparece lo que quiero desaparecer

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un menú para una página y quiero desaparecer la parte que dice `ul class="nav__responsive-ul"`.

Cuando pongo el `display:none;` no pasa nada, sigue apareciendo esa división, este es el código:

```
<header>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav__ul">
      <li class="nav__li"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="nav__li"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-group"></i><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
      <li class="nav__li"><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar"></i><a href="#">Horarios</a></li>
      <li class="nav__li"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i><a href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav__responsive-ul">
      <div class="nav__responsive-button"></div>
      <div class="nav__li-container"></div>
      <li class="nav__responsive-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="nav__responsive-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-group"></i><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
      <li class="nav__responsive-li"><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar"></i><a href="#">Horarios</a></li>
      <li class="nav__responsive-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i><a href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

En el CSS pongo:

```css
.nav__responsive-ul {
  display: none;
}
```

pero sigue saliendo.

[image: vistapgweb]

Así es como se ve, sigue apareciendo el otro menú o sección. Acabo de revisar lo del caché pero de todas formas sigue igual.

El código completo del HTML:

```
<!DOCTYbE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CSS#1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" tybe="text/css" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" tybe="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f6764f1e81.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav__ul">
          <li class="nav__li"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="nav__li"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-group"></i><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
          <li class="nav__li"><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar"></i><a href="#">Horarios</a></li>
          <li class="nav__li"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i><a href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav__responsive-ul">
          <div class="nav__responsive-button"></div>
          <div class="nav__li-container"></div>
          <li class="nav__responsive-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="nav__responsive-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-group"></i><a href="#">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
          <li class="nav__responsive-li"><i class="fa-regular fa-calendar"></i><a href="#">Horarios</a></li>
          <li class="nav__responsive-li"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i><a href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Este es todo el código `normalize.css`:

```
/*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | 

github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

/* Document
   ========================================================================== */
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/**
 * 1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
 */

html {
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/* Sections
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the margin in all browsers.
 */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Render the `main` element consistently in IE.
 */

main {
  display: block;
}

/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
 * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
 */

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box; /* 1 */
  height: 0; /* 1 */
  overflow: visible; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
 */

a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove the bottom border in Chrome 57-
 * 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
 */

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none; /* 1 */
  text-decoration: underline; /* 2 */
  text-decoration: underline dotted; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
 * all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10.
 */

img {
  border-style: none;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
 * 2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
 */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit; /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  margin: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Show the overflow in IE.
 * 1. Show the overflow in Edge.
 */

button,
input { /* 1 */
  overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
 * 1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
 */

button,
select { /* 1 */
  text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 */

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

/**
 * Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
 */

button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}

/**
 * Correct the padding in Firefox.
 */

fieldset {
  padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
 * 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
 * 3. Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out
 *    `fieldset` elements in all browsers.
 */

legend {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  color: inherit; /* 2 */
  display: table; /* 1 */
  max-width: 100%; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 3 */
  white-space: normal; /* 1 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/**
 * Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE 10+.
 */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10.
 * 2. Remove the padding in IE 10.
 */

[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
 */

[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
 * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
 */

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
 */

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
 */

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/* Interactive
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Add the correct display in Edge, IE 10+, and Firefox.
 */

details {
  display: block;
}

/*
 * Add the correct display in all browsers.
 */

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/* Misc
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10+.
 */

template {
  display: none;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10.
 */

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

El código HTML completo lo subí anteriormente y lo único que tengo del CSS es esto:

```
.nav__responsive-ul {
  display: none;
}
```

Y no funciona.

Comment: He probado tu código y funciona. No se ve el menú que quieres esconder. Es más, en la edición que han hecho de la pregunta, en el snippet no se muestra el segundo menú. Puedes poner una captura de como se ve en tu web? Viste tema de caché??

Comment: A priori funciona perfecto, puede que tengas mal linkeado el archivo css, prueba poner un background-color, o algo para asegurarte de que los estilos están funcionando cuando los seteas en el archivo CSS..

Comment: Ya subí una imagen de como me aparece todavía el segundo menú. también probé con el background color pero si lo tengo bien citado o linkeado.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que ese div mal cerrado no está haciendo conflicto? (El `</div>` sobrante antes de `</ul></nav> </header>`)

Comment: Pon todo el código que estas usando para probar.

Comment: Vuelvo a decirte que pongas todo el código. Con lo que has puesto y la única clase CSS que conocemos no se puede replicar. Ya probé y todo funciona, quizás sea por conflicto entre archivos CSS, pon todo, hasta lo del **normalize.css**

Comment: Prueba cambiando el nombre del archivo CSS y linkea ese nuevo CSS.

Comment: Por cierto, aquí yo si lo veo [funcionar](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/zYMKgyR).

Comment: Acabo de probar cambiando el nombre del archivo CSS pero tampoco me funcionó. Es extraño porque acá también me funciona a mí pero dentro del editor de código no.

Comment: Dentro del editor de código??? Navegador querrás decir?

Comment: Si si o sea en el navegador no se ve reflejado lo que quiero quitar.

Answer (score 0):

Probé el código que subiste y también me funcionó sin problemas, lo único que podría recomendar, dado el hecho que no encuentro el error que comentas, es que tu archivo de estilo.css deberías declararlo después del script de fontawesome, ya que la idea es poder sobre-escribir cualquier instrucción css que se declare con anterioridad.

Intenta abrir tu archivo html en otros navegadores para ver si se sigue replicando el problema.

Comment: Hola, acabo de intentar de esta forma pero tampoco me funcionó. Probé con el navegador edge y el resultado es el mismo. Ahora creo que todo es un problema de navegador pero igual no se como solucionarlo:(